# what is the advance of module over component in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Angular project, one can create multiple module besides `app.module`. My question is what is the necessity or advantage of extra module while i can group up my task with component? I will be so glad if you explain what is the advantages of module over component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As example: Lazy loading

Comment: As example: Third party librairies

Comment: Official doc: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#angular-modularity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, you are comparing apples to oranges. Module is piece of code, or group of pieces of code. Component is also a piece of something, but from functional point of view. In other words - it can be that there are many components in particular module, while one component belongs to particular module. Putting more components into module is good idea if you want to move them as a whole.

Comment: But to use one component from one module to  app.module i have to export it and then import it . Rather isnt it good to create all the component in one module. then i don't have to this all the manual stuff by hand? @michal

Comment: Idea of architecture is to "separate concerns". Having separate modules for different application needs means that for instance you can have many developers working on same app without constant issues. That is possible since they are agreed what each of them is changing. Having one module means everything can use everything - so no one knows. Besides that - all application must be tested, since changes can lead to problems in every piece. So in small app - that is not a big issue - but please think big... ;)